# website contact form (site sucker website)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have downloaded a website using site sucker and I have all the html files. The website was developed using a CRM (it's my new client's website which I have to upload to my server asap and they don't have credentials for the same). I have a contact form which I want to make it work

Form code:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" class="dmRespDesignRow" locale="ENGLISH"> 
    <div class="dmforminput required small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol" id="1289337126"> 
        <label for="dmform-0" id="1623474142">Name:</label> 
        <input name="dmform-0" type="text" id="1049346235"/>
        <input name="name" value="Name" type="hidden" id="1808095320"/>
    </div> 
    <div class="dmforminput required small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol" id="1229775582"> 
        <label for="dmform-1" id="1413734224">Email:</label> 
        <input name="dmform-1" type="email" id="1874224805"/><input name="email" value="Email" type="hidden" id="1790388701"/>
    </div> 
    <div class="dmforminput required small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol" id="1182638845">
        <label for="dmform-2" id="1659409819">Phone:</label> 
        <input name="dmform-2" type="tel" id="1363423394"/><input name="phone" value="Phone" type="hidden" id="1562324064"/>
    </div> 
    <div class="dmforminput dmRespDesignCol small-12 newLine large-12 medium-12" id="1310223649"> 
        <label for="dmform-3" id="1594580770">Message:</label> 
        <textarea name="message" id="1731760981"></textarea> 
        <input name="message2" value="Message" type="hidden" id="1794081407"/>
    </div> 
    <div class="dmformsubmit dmWidget R" preserve_css="true" id="1012153111">
        <input class="" name="submit" value="Send" type="submit" id="1446531284"/>
    </div> 
    <!--<input name="dmformsendto" value="O0wrseIfFLsSlLR4GAldF3Dy0PQjrXVAFxL5GhwSjRb9oqY0OVrc11ouhyoy2GDw/aszBHJnGyRKqT/UtxxJVGSoojrduF5h" preserve_css="true" type="hidden" id="1937799400" data-success-page="" data-dec="true"/>-->
    <input class="dmActionInput" name="action" value="form_email.php" type="hidden" id="1733868877"/><input name="dmformsubject" value="Form Message" preserve_css="true" type="hidden" id="1339178452" data-success-page=""/>
</form>
```

I tried creating a new file i.e form_email.php and adding as  action in the form but no luck. If I create a separate form test file (plain html without any classes) it works using that php file but doesn't work when integrating it with the actual form. I am not able to figure out what's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using JavaScript to intercept the form the `action` attribute should be added to the `form` tag, and not to an input. Example:
`<form name="contactform" method="post" action="form_email.php" class="dmRespDesignRow" locale="ENGLISH">`

In addition you must make sure that `form_email.php` is being correctly requested. If the file's location is not within the same directory the HTML file is (or the directory in which the CMS designated as such) you must fix the action attribute so that it points to the correct location. For example, if `form_email.php` is one level up (in the directory above the HTML file) you would reference it as such: `action="../form_email.php"`.